# Qt - How to delete log files after 30 days and the filename is not fixed

Tags: c++, qt

I need to delete log files that were created in a folder after 30 days. The files were created using below code:

```
QDateTime local(QDateTime::currentDateTime());
QString dir = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
dir = dir+"/log/";
QString filename = dir+"console_"+local.date().toString("yyyyMMdd")+QString("_%1").arg(logPostfix,3, 10, QChar('0'))+".log";
QFile file(filename);
```

So, the log file will be named as console_currentDate_000.log. Now, I want to delete those files in the folder after 30 days. How can I check the exact filename and delete it after 30 days. The reason I want to check the exact filename is because, if I rename the filename, it won't delete the file. Means, I want to keep the log file. For example, keep_console_Date_000.log or console_Date_000_keep.log. Below is the code that I have tried but I don't know how to check the exact filename or pattern.

```
void deleteoldfiles()
{
    QDate day(QDate::currentDate());
    day = day.addDays(-30); // Set for previous 30 days

    QString path = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
    path = path+"/log/";

    QString filename = QString("console_????????_%1.log").arg(logPostfix,3, 10, QChar('0'));

    QDir dir(path);
    QFileInfoList result = dir.entryInfoList( QDir::Files, QDir::DirsFirst);

    for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++)
    {
        QFileInfo file = result.at(i);
        if(result.at(i).fileName() == filename)
        {
            QDate filecreated = result.at(i).created().date();

            if(filecreated.daysTo(day)>0)
            {
                QString filepath = file.absoluteFilePath();
                QDir deletefile;
                deletefile.setPath(filepath);
                deletefile.remove(filepath);
                print_log("File "+filepath+" is deleted!!");
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Off topic but... can I suggest that a better policy might be to simply *move* the log files you want to keep into a separate directory.  That way you can simply remove all files in the standard log directory that are more than 30 days old.

Comment: Do you have to use Qt for this? Because, typically on a Linux host, I would create a short bash script and have it executed once a day as a cron. Would this also work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the other overload of the [`QDir::entryInfoList`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#entryInfoList) method, which receives a list of name filter parameters. Also, take a look at the [wildcards matching](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#qregexp-wildcard-matching).

```
void deleteoldfiles(int days)
{
  const QDate today = QDate::currentDate();
  const QString path = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/log/";

  QString filter("console_%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1_%1%1%1.log"); // pattern
  filter = filter.arg("[0123456789]"); // valid characters

  Q_FOREACH (auto fileInfo, QDir(path).entryInfoList(QStringList(filter), QDir::Files)) {
    if (fileInfo.created().date().daysTo(today) > days) {
      QString filepath = fileInfo.absoluteFilePath();
      QDir deletefile;
      deletefile.setPath(filepath);
      deletefile.remove(filepath);
      qDebug() << "File " + filepath + " is deleted!";
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you simply want to delete everything but file containing the *keep* string, it can be simplified to

```
void deleteoldfiles(int days)
{
  const QDate today = QDate::currentDate();
  const QString path = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/log/";

  Q_FOREACH (auto fileInfo, QDir(path).entryInfoList(QStringList("console_*.log"), QDir::Files)) {
    if (fileInfo.fileName().contains("keep")) continue;
    if (fileInfo.created().date().daysTo(today) > days) {
      QString filepath = fileInfo.absoluteFilePath();
      QDir deletefile;
      deletefile.setPath(filepath);
      deletefile.remove(filepath);
      qDebug() << "File " + filepath + " is deleted!";
    }
  }
}
```

---

PS: another good option for dealing with logs is [boost::log](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/log/doc/html/index.html), a bit complex to setup but has many powerful options, including *file collectors* which can do this job automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks @cbuchart. It is working. But partially working. Because it doesn't met this condition, if the file was renamed as console_Date_000_keep.log (the end of the filename is added with a name), it should not be deleted.

Comment: Oops, sorry, forgot about it. I've updated the answer so the filtering actually returns only files with the pattern you want. I've also added a modification to the original code in case it is enough for you.

Comment: Nice. It is working as expected. Thanks a lot @cbuchart!